# Possible error in reformulation of Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: number-theory

I was trying to reformulate Goldbach's conjecture in terms of the sum of divisors function $\sigma_1(n)$, but I think there is an error in my approach:

I begin with the following straightforward proposition: If
$$\sigma_1(n_1)+\sigma_1(n_2)-n_1-n_2=2$$
then both $n_1$ and $n_2$ are primes. That is, a pair $n_1$ and $n_2$ verifying that condition is a pair of prime numbers.
Then we can express Goldbach's conjecture as:
$$2n=\alpha_1+\alpha_2 ∣\, \sigma_1(\alpha_1)+\sigma_1(\alpha_2)-\alpha_1-\alpha_2=2 \quad \forall n>2, \quad n, \alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb{N}^+$$
Now, here is where I think I failed: I substituted the condition
$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2=\sigma_1(\alpha_1)+\sigma_1(\alpha_2)-2$$
into the first equality, so that
$$2n=\sigma_1(\alpha_1)+\sigma_1(\alpha_2)-2$$
or
$$2(n+1)=\sigma_1(\alpha_1)+\sigma_1(\alpha_2) \quad \forall n>2$$
I think it's wrong (in the sense that is not equivalent) because the set of values $\{\sigma_1(n)\}$ seems to be "denser" than the set of primes, but I'm not a proper mathematician and I tend to fall into logical mistakes. Thank you in advance.